# Subquery is returning more than one value? Not getting a result set?

Tags: sql-server

> Write a SELECT statement that returns two columns: VendorName and LargestInv
>   (LargestInv is the correlation name of the subquery)
>
> Subquery portion:
>   SELECT statement that returns the largest InvoiceTotal from the Invoices table (you will need to perform the JOIN within the subquery in one of the clauses).
>
> Sort the results by LargestInv from largest to smallest.(Subquery Must be in the Select statement)

I have tried this but My subqueries returning more than one value

```
USE AP

SELECT VendorName, (SELECT MAX(InvoiceTotal) FROM Invoices JOIN Vendors
                        ON Invoices.VendorID = Vendors.VendorID
                    GROUP BY Invoices.VendorID) AS LargestInv
FROM Vendors
```

Comment: Your sub query has `GROUP BY VendorName`, so it'll return 1 row per name for the correlated query. THis *implies* vendors have more than one name, which seems like a a data integrity issue.

Comment: I just did VendorName in the group By because VendorID was showing the same error

Comment: *"because VendorID was showing the same error"* I doubt that, based on  the subquery and it's join.

Comment: It does I'm looking at it right now

Comment: Take OUT the join in the subquery. You simply correlate the subquery to the outer. E.g., (select max() from dbo.Invoices as inv where inv.VendorID = Vendors.VendorID).

Comment: Show us some sample data that we can replicate that with then, @Randy , as (without offence) I don't believe you because that isn't how that query would work. ThThere is no way that subquery will give multiple rows now. That implies we don't have the full story here. If you drop the `GROUP BY` the result would be the same (it **won't** error)

Comment: And now would be a good time to read the [documentation about correlated subqueries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-ver15) since it has an very similar example of this

Comment: How can I show you guys some my sample data? Is there a way to give you the query file that creates the database? I'm using the database from 'Murach's SQL Server 2016 for developers' textbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is scope.

The sub-query shouldn't be joining to the `Vendor` table if the goal is a correlated sub-query. The "correlated" part comes from joining the results of the inner query (the sub-query) to the outer query.

As written, you're finding VendorID inside the sub-query and the results aren't correlated to the outer query at all. Hence your error message.

```
SELECT 
  VendorName, 
  (SELECT MAX(InvoiceTotal) 
   FROM Invoices 
   WHERE Invoices.VendorID = Vendors.VendorID
  ) AS LargestInv
FROM Vendors
ORDER BY LargestInv DESC;
```

**Edit (extended explanation):**

A correlated sub-query isn't designed to pull up a full result set, like the sub-query you were writing at first. It's designed to go over to another table and use a value (or values) from the outer query to bring back a single result, one row at a time.

In this case, using the VendorID from the Vendors table, go over to Invoices, calculate a MAX value "WHERE" the VendorID in Invoices matches the VendorID ON THIS ROW, bring that single value back, then, next row, go back and do that again. And again and again.

It's *one* way to get the data, but it's not usually efficient. Later, though, you'll learn to use correlated sub-queries in `(NOT) EXISTS` clauses, and in that context they tend to be extremely efficient. Story for another day, but it's one reason the construct is important to know.

So, your way was good, because it was set based and would tend to be more efficient as a sub-query in the `FROM` clause, but this way, row by row, is important to understand conceptually.

Comment: If I take out the Join and type what you have I get a red line under the VendorName in the select clause saying its an invalid column name(Can't be fixed with Vendors.VendorName) and its required in the question to use a join in the subquery. I have to use it in there

Comment: Sorry. I was going too fast. In a correlated sub-query, the relationship is defined in a `WHERE` clause, not an `ON`. I corrected the query. Give it another spin. Should be good. https://rextester.com/GLQQ91793

Comment: Thank You so much!!! You just saved my grade in the class. If you would could you explain to me in layman's term why this solution works compared to my code? I'm new to SQL and I'm having a hard time understanding these coding challenges. Thanks again:)

Comment: I added some stuff. If nothing else, some good keywords for you to search on. :) Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

```
SELECT VendorName, LargestInv.MaxI
FROM Vendors
FROM (
  SELECT VendorName, MAX(InvoiceTotal) as MaxI 
  FROM Invoices 
  JOIN Vendors ON Invoices.VendorID = Vendors.VendorID
  GROUP BY VendorName
) AS LargestInv ON LargestInv.VendorName = Vendors.VendorName
```

Now having more than one in the sub-query won't give you an error and you can look at the results.

Comment: I wish I could do it this way but its a requirement to have the subquery in the select clause

Comment: @Randy -- ok when you do it this way to see multiple rows for each vender name?

Comment: I edited the OP It was 'GROUP  BY Invoices.VendorID' and it still shows Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Yes @Randy I understand the problem you have more than one with the same max value.